# JPA persist a map from an Embeddable class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, model

I have three related classes as follows:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Job implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "JOB_ID")
    private String jobId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private List<Task> tasks;

}
```

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "taskId", scope = Task.class)
public class Task implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TASK_ID")
    private String taskId;

    @Embedded
    private DockerEnvironment environment;

}
```

and

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
@JsonTypeName(value = "docker")
public class DockerEnvironment extends AbstractInstallation {

    @Column(name = "DOCKER_IMAGE")
    private String dockerImage;

    @Column(name = "PORT")
    @JsonProperty("port")
    private String port;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "DOCKER_ENV_VARS_MAPPING", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DOCKER_TASK_ID") })
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "ENVVAR_KEY")
    @Column(name = "ENVVAR_VALUE")
    private Map<String, String> environmentVars;

}
```

I send a REST request to create a job with the following JSON part:

```
.
.
.
"tasks": [{
    "installation": {
        "environmentVars": {
            "MYSQL_DATABASE": "NAME",
            "MYSQL_USER": "USER",
            "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD": "admin"
            }
.
.
.
```

At a certain point in my code I save manually te newly created objects by doing:

```
repositoryService.saveTask(newTask);
repositoryService.saveJob(newJob);
repositoryService.flush();
```

While debugging I see everything fine, but after in DB `environmentVars` table (`DOCKER_ENV_VARS`) is empty.
Any insights regarding what is wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove extension from AbstractInstallation and see if problem still present

Comment: Thanks for your response Artem. I tried as you suggested but nothing changes.

Comment: Saw your solution below. You could try to create custom repository function with @Query where you pass task itself and job id

Comment: it can be a good idea, thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed the issue by adapting how I save the data:

```
repositoryService.saveTask(newTask);
tasks.add(newTask);
newJob.setTasks(tasks);
repositoryService.saveJob(newJob);
tasks.forEach(repositoryService::saveTask); // This added line
repositoryService.flush();
```

I don't know why it happens knowing that I already tested to cascade persistence from Job but it did not fix the issue.
Anyway, now it works.

Comment: You were not saving your tasks at all. Saving the Job only.. saves the job, even if it references new tasks because you told JPA to cascade refresh operations over the relationship, and nothing else.

Comment: How come? I had a `repositoryService.saveTask(newTask);` instruction

Comment: I take it back - seems like strange behavior from Hibernate that shouldn't be expected. Does it work if you don't save the newJob instance (and so also don't call tasks.forEach(repositoryService::saveTask))? Also check that your JSON JsonIdentityInfo isn't part of the problem. My understanding is that it will exclude environment info if the task is in the graph multiple times, which might be a problem if the same task instance isn't used on deserialization. Check exactly what is in the Job tasks list.